# What database tool to use on Linux to read an as/400 database?

Tags: linux, odbc, ibm-midrange, redhat

From Linux (Red Hat dist), we need to read an AS400 database.  We have the ODBC driver to connect, what's the best query tool?

Comment: Could you provide some more details into what you're trying to achieve? Hard to determine the "best" without knowing wether you're aiming for stability / portability / performance / etc.

Comment: Actually, best doesn't even need apply.  I'm just looking for anything!  Our company is interfacing with a third party system that runs on Linux.  They need to be able to read our database from their system.  Any Linux ODBC database tool would work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any more info.  The best I can do is come up with an analogy:  If I had a Windows PC and I needed to view a foreign computer database via ODBC, I'd use MS Access to link to it.  What is the equivalent of MS Access on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kexi](http://kexi-project.org/) calls itself "Microsoft Access for Linux", and it's pretty good, but the [ODBC driver](http://kexi-project.org/wiki/wikiview/index.php@ODBCDriver.html) isn't quite there yet.

A similar program is [OpenOffice.org BASE](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html).  IMO, Kexi is a better overall product, but Base has an ODBC driver.

Lighter-weight graphical tools for databases with ODBC drivers include [Datakiosk](http://extragear.kde.org/apps/datakiosk/) and [Tora](http://tora.sourceforge.net) (which, despite its name, works with more than just Oracle).

What's "best"?  Depends on your tastes and your needs.  This is by no means an all-inclusive list.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and Quantum DB